# why to choose abstract(without default implementation) over interface vb.net?

Tags: .net, interface, abstract

I am confused between Interfaces and Abstract classes I know the technical differences between them like interfaces can’t have fields while abstract can, also interfaces apply the multiple inheritance while abstract classes can’t.

I am wondering if I have an abstract class with 4 methods but without default implementation, and I have interface with 4 methods too sure without implementation,   at that moment what is the difference between using them?  They look the same for me !

when I can choose abstract class over interface in that case ?

Comment: In a *corner* case where you have an abstract class with 0% of the methods implemented, they do indeed resemble interfaces. But that's far from the *usual* usage where some or all of the methods will have a (default) implementation.

Comment: In some scenario, you can declare the interface public and the abstract class internal or private in order for any foreign code to know and use only the interface and your abstract class providing to you a default (or empty) implementation of the interface. Then you will derive from the abstract class some other (concrete) classes for specific needs that are not common to each other and thus cannot be implemented directly into the abstract (base) class. This hierarchy can be usefull when you (really) need different similar classes to share some common behavior but want to hide their existance.

Comment: thanks all for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule to select them is the following:

1. To specify the methods a class has to implement use always an interface as you can use multiple inheritance with interfaces.
2. If you have some implementation that has to be shared between the implementors of the interface use an abstract class.

If you have an empty abstract class it should be replaced with an interface always.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes offer at least three advantages over interfaces:

1. Abstract classes can have fields, but interfaces can't.  While public-facing objects should not have public fields, it may sometimes be advantageous for classes *whose instances will never be exposed to the public* to do so.  A field of type `Int32`, for example, can be safely can be safely passed as a `ref` parameter to a method that updates it via e.g. `Interlocked.Increment`; a property cannot.  While it may be possible to combine a property of type `Int32` and also provide methods like `AtomicIncrementFoo`, using a field can avoid the need for a lot of boilerplate code.
2. Abstract classes can overload operators, including implicit and explicit type conversions.  Interfaces cannot do so, at least in C#.
3. Abstract classes can define default implementations for methods, but even when 99% of the classes implementing an interface would use identical code for a method, every single one must separately define `void SomeMethod(int Foo) { MyInterfaceHelper.SomeMethod(this, Foo); }`.  Not only does that entail a lot of boilerplate code, but a desire to minimize boilerplate code frequently causes interface authors to omit things that interfaces really should contain.

I don't know that there's any reason .NET and the associated languages couldn't give interfaces the above abilities, but as yet they don't.